# Images not displaying on production build, only in dev (webpack/sass-loader)

Tags: javascript, image, webpack, sass, sass-loader

When running my app on webpack dev server, all my image files are working whether as img tags in my index.html or background-image: url()..

Running my project though in production build, I am getting file reference errors that they cannot be found.

```
GET file:///img/featured.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
GET file:///img/header-img1-1.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I added the copy webpack plugin as I thought this would move all images from my src/img folder to my img folder inside dist.

Should I be using the contentBase option for webpack-dev-server? Or is the copy-webpack-plugin not getting the correct reference? Super confused

Project tree:

```
- webpack.config.js
- package.json
- .babelrc
- src
  - js
    - index.js
    - ...
  - img
    - ALL IMAGES LOCATED HERE
  - scss
    - layout
      - landing.scss
      - brands.scss 
    - base
  - index.html
```

inside landing.scss
i have used

```
background: url('~/img/img-title.png')
```

same in other files like brands.scss

```
background: url('~/img/img-title.png')
```

Which has all worked fine, and I think I've confused myself with how images are referenced with webpack/sass loader, and can't seem to work out how to get the image paths to work for both dev/production, i can only seem to get one working at a time.

production tree:

```
- dist
  - css
  - img
  - js
  - index.html
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```js
const path = require('path');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const extractPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'css/main.css'
});

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ScriptExtPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env) => {
  const isProduction = env.production === true

  return {
 entry: './src/js/index.js',
 output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: 'js/bundle.js', 
 },
 module: {
   rules: [
  {
       test: /\.js$/,
       include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    use: 'babel-loader' 
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$|\.scss$/,
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    use: extractPlugin.extract({  
   fallback: "style-loader",
   use: [
     { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 2, sourceMap: true }},
     { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { sourceMap: true, plugins: () => [autoprefixer] }},
     { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true }},
   ],
    }) 
  },
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: ['html-loader']
  },
  {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
    use: [
   {
        loader: 'url-loader',
     options: {
    limit: 1000,
    name: 'img/[name].[ext]',
     }
   }
    ]
  }
   ]
 },
 plugins: [
   extractPlugin,
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ 
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: true,
  template: './src/index.html'
   }),
   new ScriptExtPlugin({
     defaultAttribute: 'async'
   }),
   new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
   new CopyWebpackPlugin([
     {from:'src/img',to:'img'} 
   ]), 
 ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're using different folder structure on production than on local, i.e. on local, it's just ***http://localhost:PORT/app***, but on prod, it must be similar to ***http://produrl/Some_Folder/app***

Now coming to actual issue - It's your CSS loader.

By default **css-loader**, has ***url=true***, causing all URLs to be mapped relative to root. Hence this works for you -

```
background: url('~/img/img-title.png')
```

but this doesn't

```
background: url('../../img/img-title.png')
```

Just set ***url=false***, and you'll be able to provide relative URL and it'll load for all enviorments correctly.

Comment: Ahh thank you incredibly for this! I never would have imagined it was the css-loader, after reading mostly issues with urls and sass loader.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm in same boat currently, but my issues is worse as there's node components involved.

Answer (score 3):

While the accepted answer may works in your specific scenario, I think there is a better solution that do not involve disabling `css-loader` `url()` handling and will works better in most of situation.

### Tilde `~` problem

When you use `~` to import something in css, `css-loader` will search for that file inside *node_modules*. Your images are inside *src/img* folder so you do **not** need tilde `~` to import your images.

### `url()` problem

[sass-loader doesn't not resolve `url()` correctly](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#problems-with-url) if they are not in the same directory of the entry-file.

In your specific example you import some urls inside *src/scss/layout/landing.scss* and *src/scss/layout/brands.scss* but I guess your main scss entry point is inside *src/scss* folder.

Note: for *"main scss entry point"* I mean the scss file that you import inside your javascript entry point *src/js/index.js*

So, in your example, every images imported within a scss file that is **not** inside *src/scss* folder will trow an error.

To solve this problem use [resolve-url-loader](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader) which resolves relative paths in url() statements based on the original source file.

```
[
  { loader: 'css-loader'}, // set `importLoaders: 3` if needed but should works fine without it
  { loader: 'postcss-loader'},
  { loader: 'resolve-url-loader' }, // add this
  { loader: 'sass-loader',
    // sourceMap is required for 'resolve-url-loader' to work
    options: { sourceMap: true }
  }
]
```

### `CopyWebpackPlugin` is optional

Based on your configuration you do not need `CopyWebpackPlugin` because your images are already handle by `url-loader`.

Note: [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader) doesn't output your images but inline them, images are outputted by [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) when the file is greater than the limit (in bytes).

`file-loader` will output your images in *dist/img* folder, because you set `name: 'img/[name].[ext]'`, and you set `output.path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think your issue is just in how you're referencing the image in your scss.

Based on your folder structure it should be:

`background: url('../../img/img-title.png')`

Comment: hey @RobIsAnxious I have tried that, but I get a build error of:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../img/image-title.png'

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the "publicPath" URL (which is relative to the server root) to match the file structure.

```js
//webpack.config.js
 ...
   module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[ext]",
              outputPath: "assets/images/",
              publicPath: "/other-dir/assets/images/"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```